# Styling filenames and extension in LaTeX

Tags: minted

I have a question that's more about style:
How do you style your filenames and extensions in LaTeX?

Right now I'm mostly using `\mintinline{bash}{.fileextension}` or `\mintinline{bash}{file.ext}` like in the image.

[image: code excerpt where a .Rmd file extension is styled]

I was wondering what is the convention to style these?

Comment: why minted? there is no structure to parse, why not `\texttt{file.ext}` ?

Comment: I was already using minted for actual code snippets so thats the why. I know it probably isn't the best thing to do so thats why I asked the question. Hadn't heard of `\texttt{}` but it looks good!

Comment: texttt is a standard built in latex command, it should be in any latex tutorial, it will work in all latex contexts.   `\mintinline{bash}{.fileextension}` requires allowing shell escape, a system call to python, writing several temporary files, mis-parsing `.fileextension` as bash syntax, then reading in the file.

Comment: okay, thank you for that clarification!